# Printing None and NaN values in Pandas dataframe produces confusing results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan, nonetype

I am using a SQL query to obtain some data from a SQL Server database using Pandas read_sql() function. After some initial hiccups, it all seems to be working well. However, using print() to display the extracted data gives an extremely confusing output.

At the time the database is interrogated, I know that the most recent rows of one of the tables have not yet been populated. Therefore, the top rows of a column contain strings whilst the bottom rows contain None. This can be simplified using the following dataframe.

```
    id         text
0    1   some words   <-- top rows contain strings
1    2         None
2    3         None
3    4         None
4    5         None
5    6         None
6    7         None
7    8         None
8    9         None
9   10         None   <-- bottom rows contain None
```

This can be generated using:

```
import pandas as pd
tempDF = pd.DataFrame({'id':    np.arange(1,11),
                       'text': ['some words'] + [None]*9})
```

When I print the dataframe in Python 3.4, I get the expected output, namely:

```
   id        text
0   1  some words
1   2        None
2   3        None
3   4        None
4   5        None
5   6        None
6   7        None
7   8        None
8   9        None
9  10        None
```

However, when printing large dataframes, the output is automatically split to display only the top and the bottom rows. As this demo only has 10 rows, I will set the display parameters to make the split even with this small dataframe:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 8, 'display.max_columns', 3):
    print(tempDF)
```

However, now I get the following output:

```
    id        text
0    1  some words
1    2        None
2    3        None
3    4        None
..  ..         ...
6    7         NaN
7    8         NaN
8    9         NaN
9   10         NaN
```

It seems that if all the values below the split are None then they are interpreted as NaN. However, the same values above the split (where there are also some genuine strings) are interpreted as None.

There seems to be lots of debate about the differences between None and NaN. Displaying the same data as two different types seems to be really confusing. I don't know whether this would be caused by Python or Pandas. Is this an intended feature or a bug?

Comment: This is certainly not an intended feature. Can you issue a bug report? https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/new

Comment: Even weirder is that when the `text` column is all  `None`s, the display will be NaN on top and bottom. This is certainly a bug

Comment: Bug report submitted.

Comment: As a reference, the issue is tracked here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12045